# Как отправить ajax запрос с localhost на удалённый сервер? (cors error)

Tags: javascript, php, cors

Есть скрипт на php на удалённом сервер и js скрипт на http://localhost:3000
Ajax запросы с localhost:3000 на сервер обрубаются политикой CORS. Подскажите пожалуйста где и какие заголовки нужно прописать чтобы разрешить запросы с параметрами.

Вот код запроса на localhost:3000.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    let data = JSON.stringify({subscriber:'test@yandex.ru'});

    axios.post('https://мой-сервер/mailsend.php',data).then(
        response => {
            if (response) {
                console.log('response', response)
            }
        }
    )
</script>
```

Comment: На удалённом сервере. Примеров и инструкций в сети вообще и на этом ресурсе в частности миллион

Comment: mozilla mdn, там все расписано